# Rule Item: how to check if it has to be re-run?

Tags: qbs

In my case, `Rule` has to be invoked upon environment changes (svn revision of working directory) instead of changes of input files. So, depending on `alwaysRun`, my rule is invoked either never (failing build) or always (forcing dependers to be rebuilt).

What I need is either:

1. a way to check if `Rule` has to be run or not
2. a way to cache rule output somehow, for dependers only to be rebuilt when necessary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rules and Commands are re-run not only due to input changes, but also if properties used in them change. So in your case, you will want to define a property that corresponds to the svn repository state and refer to it in your rule and/or command. Then the re-execution will happen if and only if it is necessary. 
Note that in qbs 1.10, such a property is provided automatically via the vcs module: http://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qbs/vcs-module.html

Comment: am I correct, that properties can only be changed at evaluation, but not build time?

Comment: Yes, but re-evaluation will be done on an as-needed basis when re-building.

Comment: can you suggest how exactly re-evaluation prior to build step can be achieved? Forcing execution of all probes is not an option

Comment: A Probe is re-run if one of its properties changes. So having a Probe property that uses File.lastModified() on a relevant svn file such as wc.db should do the trick.